# Rails link_to not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to put in a `link_to` on my table to go to the `show` action but it is putting the URL as `/admin/vulnerabilities.object_id` instead of `/admin/vulnerabilities/object_id`
my index view is:

```
...
<% @vulnerabilities.each do |vulnerability| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=link_to vulnerability.id, admin_vulnerabilities_path(vulnerability) %></td>
    <td><%= vulnerability.type %></td>
    <td><%=h truncate(vulnerability.description, :length => 80) %></td>
    <td><%= vulnerability.published %></td>
    <td><%= vulnerability.modified %></td>
    <td><%= link_to vulnerability.href, vulnerability.href , target: :_blank %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
...
```

I have a `show.html.erb` template setup and my `show` action is as follows:

```
def show
  @vulnerabilities = Vulnerability.find(params[:id])
end
```

From what I can see, this should work but when clicking the links it just redirects to the index page, effectively refreshing it and not using my show page at all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the relevant parts of your `routes.rb` file to your question, but I speculate that the problem is that `admin_vulnerabilities_path(vulnerability)` should be `admin_vulnerability_path(vulnerability)`.

Comment: @jvillian's got this I reckon - you might also want to rename the variable in your show view to the singular `@vulnerability` to avoid confusion. FYI you can use `rake routes -g vulnerability` or `rake routes -g vulnerabilities` to check the routing, as of Rails 5.

Comment: Yup, that got it! I forgot about the singular paths, still getting my head around the single/plural usages!

Comment: Posted as an answer to close the loop. Feel free to upvote/accept for future folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you added the relevant parts of your routes.rb file to your question, but I speculate that the problem is that `admin_vulnerabilities_path(vulnerability)` should be `admin_vulnerability_path(vulnerability)`.

Also, as noted in the comments, it is probably better to use `@vulnerability` as your instance name since `find` will return a single record.